# Becoming an astronaut engineer

Tags: engineering

Which engineering branch will be most suitable for becoming an astronaut and what other options I have if I
 want to become an astronaut with an engineering background?

Comment: While this is off-topic here for being a shopping question from the academic point of view, it *might* be suitable on [Space Exploration SE](http://space.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 5):

On [NASA's website](http://astronauts.nasa.gov/content/broch00.htm#bqr) you can read:

> Astronaut Candidate (Non-Piloting background)
>
> Bachelor’s degree from an accredited institution in **engineering, biological science, physical science, or mathematics**.

And:

> [...] The following degree fields, while related to engineering and the
>   sciences, **are not considered qualifying**:
>
> - Degrees in Technology (Engineering Technology, Aviation Technology, Medical Technology, etc.)
> - Degrees in Psychology (except for Clinical Psychology, Physiological Psychology, or Experimental Psychology which are qualifying).
> - Degrees in Nursing.
> - Degrees in Exercise Physiology or similar fields
> - Degrees in Social Sciences (Geography, Anthropology, Archaeology, etc.).
> - Degrees in Aviation, Aviation Management, or similar fields.

Comment: This is an off-topic comment : Is very-pure mathematics is qualified?

Comment: @user565739 There have been some astronauts (past and present) with degrees in mathematics.